# git rebase falsely detects local changes in rebase

Tags: git

I am trying to do a interctive rebase squash. It's claiming that I have local changes uncommitted, but that is not the case. Any suggestions?

```
$ git status
On branch 859423-Modulize-JS-Build-Files
nothing to commit, working tree clean


$ git pull origin 859423-Modulize-JS-Build-Files
From https://tfs/marketing.marketplace
 * branch              859423-Modulize-JS-Build-Files -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.

$ git rebase -i develop
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
        MarketPlace.Web/Marketplace.WebUI/css/am/site.css
Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
Aborting
fatal: cherry-pick failed
Could not apply 8b499ab98b4f23ad30a3b8b2d5bafd9695f8405f... fully working
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try and see if the issue persists after switching branches.

```
git checkout develop
git checkout 859423-Modulize-JS-Build-Files
git rebase develop
```

See the [edit from "git cherry-pick says local changes exist, but git status says nothing"](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4264104/revisions)